# Running joblib over multiple nodes in a HPC cluster

Tags: python, parallel-processing, hpc, joblib, mpi4py

Hello I am tryning to solve a simple optimization for a million times with different inputs. For that I have the following structure:

input = list of N arrays
myfun() = Takes one array solves and returns another list as answer

Now I want to parallelize this over three nodes, where each node has 48 CPUs.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Currently, I can run a joblib parallel delayed function, but that can only work over a single node.

Currently, I can run a joblib parallel delayed function, but that can only work over a single node.

Comment: I do not think joblib can do that alone but MPI in Python can. You need to distribute your data on the node though and run the MPI application properly (typically through a HPC submission system like SLURM for example). MPI can also be used to parallelize your code on 1 node. IMHO joblib is actually not needed here.

Comment: Do you have any minimal examples on how to do this? 
Specifically, MPI should be used inside the python script or the slurm run script

Comment: SLURM is a scheduler and it typically supports MPI application (I think it was mainly designed for this in the first place). I used to run MPI jobs on HPC cluster but not since 5 years. You will certainly find better example scripts than what I can write by just typing "slurm example" on any search engine. For mpi4Py, you can read high-voted questions with the tag `[mpi4py]` on this website, or on the official website. There are even tutorials : https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html .